# Me sale este error que puede esatr mal suma() TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Tags: python

```
def funcion_decoradora(funcion_parametro):

    def funcion_interior():

        # Acciones adicionales que decoran

        print("Vamos a realizar un calculo: ")

        funcion_parametro()

        # Acciones adicinales que decoran

        print("Hemos terminado el calculo") 

@funcion_decoradora
def suma():

    print(15+20)

@funcion_decoradora
def resta():

    print(30-10)

suma()

resta()
```

Answer (score 1):

El decorador debe retornar "funcion_interior":

```
def funcion_decoradora(funcion_parametro):
    def funcion_interior():
        print("Vamos a realizar un calculo: ")
        funcion_parametro()
        print("Hemos terminado el calculo")

    return funcion_interior
```

Comment: muchas gracias eyllanesc por tu colaboración

Answer (score 0):

En la función decoradora te falto poner el `return` ya que esta función tiene que retornar en este caso mostrar el calculo que decoro

```
def funcion_decoradora(funcion_parametro):

    def funcion_interior():

        # Acciones adicionales que decoran

        print("Vamos a realizar un calculo: ")

        funcion_parametro()

        # Acciones adicinales que decoran

        print("Hemos terminado el calculo") 
    return funcion_interior
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias spider-man por tu ayuda